fzf to replace kubectx and kubens
FZF stores the argument number that is passed to it and I'm unable to reuse $1. The idea is to create a nested fzf so that we do not have to run kubectx followed by kubens to switch to correct namespace. In zsh it sets the cluster and namespace to the same value of $1 which is the cluster.
kubectl config get-contexts -o=name | fzf --bind "enter:become((/opt/homebrew/bin/kubectl config use-context {1}) ; (/opt/homebrew/bin/kubectl get namespaces -o=name | fzf --bind 'enter:become((/opt/homebrew/bin/kubectl config set-context --current --namespace={1}))'))"

